# Creating a sequence of grid points in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, grid, cell

The dimension `n` is given, we want to grid the space with equidistant points, let say in each dimension we start from `-L` to `+L` by a step size `2L/(N+1)`. Now, we would like the output to be all the *n*-dimensional vectors giving the nodal points. They are all contained in an array of `n` rows and `N^n` columns. I am wondering how to code this in MATLAB.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you please give an example with L = 5, N = 10 and n = 3?

Comment: Is n known on runtime only? If not, you can use `ndgrid`

Comment: @Rotem That'd be a matrix with 3 rows and 10^3 columns; each colim correspondents to `(i,j,k)` such that `-5<i, j, k<5`

Comment: @naltipar Yes, it's a general case not for a specific n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you look for:

```
n = 3; % no. of dimensions
L = 4; % bounds
N = 20; % no. of points
grd = cell(1,n);
[grd{:}] = ndgrid(-L:2*L/(N-1):L);
```

here `grd` is a cell array of with `n` cells, each for one dimension. Note that if you want `N` points you need to set the gap to `2*L/(N-1)` because `2*L/N` will give you `N+1` points.

```
grd = 
    [20x20x20 double]    [20x20x20 double]    [20x20x20 double]
```

If you want the output to be in an `n` by `N^n` matrix, you loop through `grd`:

```
arr = zeros(n,N^n);
for k = 1:n
    arr(k,:) = grd{k}(:).';
end
```

and you get:

```
>> size(arr)
ans =
           3        8000
```